# Creating Methods in Separate Classes

Tags: java, android, methods, onclick

I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to create a method within a separate class, and have it be able to change int values in  the main activity. If you look at this simple counter below, I want to be able to put the counter +=1 code etc in the onClicks, within a method in a separate class. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter = 0;
    TextView counterDisplay;
    Button plusOne, minusOne;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Plus One Button
        plusOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        counterDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


        plusOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                counter += 1;
                counterDisplay.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });

        // Subtract One Button
        minusOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        counterDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        minusOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                counter -= 1;
                counterDisplay.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by extracting the anonymous class to an inner class:

```
...extends Activity {

   ...
   minusOne.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
   ...

    private class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter -= 1;
            counterDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you can make that private inner class `static`. This means that it doesn't hold a reference to the outer class, the Activity, meaning it cannot change the fields in the Activity:

```
private static class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter -= 1; // ERROR - cannot resolve 
        counterDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(counter)); // ERROR cannot resolve
    }
}
```

So, what you can do is pass this class all the dependencies it needs, namely - the two buttons, the display and the counter (if needed):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ...
        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new MyClickListener(minusButton, plusButton, counterDisplay);
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        ...
    }

    ...

    private static class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Button minusButton;
        private final Button plusButton;
        private final TextView counterDisplay;

        private counter;

        MyClickListener(Button minusButton, Button plusButton, TextView counterDisplay) {
            this.minusButton = minusButton;
            this.plusButton = plusButton;
            this.counterDisplay = counterDisplay;
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

Now you can update the text:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ...
        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new MyClickListener(minusButton, plusButton, counterDisplay);
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        ...
    }

    ...

    private static class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Button minusButton;
        private final Button plusButton;
        private final TextView counterDisplay;

        private counter;

        MyClickListener(Button minusButton, Button plusButton, TextView counterDisplay) {
            this.minusButton = minusButton;
            this.plusButton = plusButton;
            this.counterDisplay = counterDisplay;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == minusButton.getId()) {
                counter--;
            } else if (v.getId() == plusButton.getId()) {
                counter++;
            }

            counterDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be a better idea to pass the counter to an AsyncTask.

Comment: How would an AsyncTask help?